# displaying message box using javascript by avoiding postback like click events. The ok, cancel buttons should only close the messgae box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i faced a situation when the user clicks on any button or linkbutton on page it should display messagebox. so i am displaying message box by addin javascript function to window.onbeforeunload.

Till now it works fine. i just want not to display the message box when the user clicks on ok or cancel button without doing any postback events.  So i kept "return false"  on ok and cancel button. When i click on these ok , cancel button its  displaying another message box in IE as "Message from web page false".

Comment: Can you please put your code here?

Comment: Your questions seems unclear to me, do you want a bunch of message boxes that do nothing? Could show us your code so we can have a better idea.

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = function () {
          if (confirm('A patient match has been found continue with "create new patient"?')) {
              return false;
          }
          else {
              return false;
          }
      };

Comment: The main aim is to not to give facility to the user to click anything except one button. I achive this functionality using javacript by keeping onbegforeunload =none

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... I question this technique in two ways:

1. Why do you expect 'return false' to consistently suppress this event for your `ok` and `cancel` buttons? Why would IE suppress the event based on a return value of `false`?
2. What's this business of attaching to the `window.onbeforeunload` event? Should you not be responding to a `click` event on these elements?

Honestly it sounds like IE is providing a reasonable action based on your code: the `onbeforeunload` event is firing, and it's displaying a messagebox of `false`, which is what you're returning.

Here's a couple of ideas.
a. Instead of using `return false` to suppress the messagebox for your `ok` and `cancel` buttons, in your callback function, use and if/then to check and see if one of these was clicked. If so, just `return` and do not execute the code for the modal.
b. Bind all buttons, links, and inputs to the `click` event, instead of `onbeforeunload`. Then use the check in (a) above in the same way.

Using jQuery to bind the event:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(e) {
        if ((e.target.id === 'ok') || (e.target.id === 'cancel')) {
            return();
        } else { 
            // display message box
        }
    })
});
```

Hope this helps!

DISCLAIMER: I haven't actually seen the code, so this is sort of a shot in the dark.